# Add reference from project with different framework c#

Tags: c#, frameworks, target

I have a legacy code that contains multiple solutions. Each solution can target different framework. E.g. The "common" solution targets framework Unity 3.5 .net full Base Class Libraries, the "core" and "creator" solutions target 4.6 framework.

I'm creating a solution that works on 4.6 framework and want to use it as a reference in the "common" project, however every time I try to do so, I get a huge list of compilation errors from "metadata could not be found" to "some nugget packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled" to "The primary reference could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly which has a higher version than the version in the current target framework"

How should one approach this issue of trying to connect a newer framework with an older one as painlessly as possible?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way around using/targeting the oldest framework compatible. _Or_ upgrading the legacy code to a newer framework, which probably goes against "as painless as possible" ...

Comment: I believe installing .net 3.5 SDK might solve some problems

Comment: ^^ oh yes. I somehow took that for granted.

Comment: .net 3.5 is installed on visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. First, pick every sln in its package and upgrade it seperately from the others in a common version. For my case it was .net framework 4.6. Then and after all errors/warnings have been resolved, build the project containing the other projects and use the references.

Hopefully it will compile successfully.